# The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I don't know where is the problem

I will very thankful for the person who will explain to me .

I need any kind person to answer me .This is my whole code nothing else .The problem which i faced is

```
 ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()
    at CreateSimpleDynamicRolloverswithAs3_fla::MainTimeline/rolloverF()
```

even I make this code as comment the error still persists

```
images_mc.setChildIndex(evt.currentTarget as MovieClip, numChildren-1);





import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.display.Shape;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var imgBorder:Shape = new Shape();
imgBorder.graphics.lineStyle(5,0xffffff,1,true,"normal");
imgBorder.graphics.drawRect(0,0,250,120);
addChild(imgBorder);

imgBorder.visible = false;

images_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER , rolloverF);
images_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT , rolloutF);

function rolloverF(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    imgBorder.visible = true;
    var borderTween:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,1,true);
    var borderW:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"width",Strong.easeOut,255,280,1,true);
    var borderH:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"height",Strong.easeOut,125,137,1,true);

    var imgW:Tween = new Tween(evt.currentTarget,"width",Strong.easeOut,255,280,1,true);
    var imgH:Tween = new Tween(evt.currentTarget,"height",Strong.easeOut,125,137,1,true);
    trace (images_mc.mc1.name);
    imgBorder.x = evt.currentTarget.x;
    imgBorder.y = evt.currentTarget.y;


    //even i make this code as comment error sitll persists
    images_mc.setChildIndex(evt.currentTarget as MovieClip, numChildren-1);
    //trace(images_mc.mc1.name);
    }

function rolloutF(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    var borderTweenBack:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);
    var borderWBack:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"width",Strong.easeOut,280,255,1,true);
    var borderHBack:Tween = new Tween(imgBorder,"height",Strong.easeOut,137,125,1,true);


    var imgWBack:Tween = new Tween(evt.currentTarget,"width",Strong.easeOut,275,250,1,true);
    var imgHBack:Tween = new Tween(evt.currentTarget,"height",Strong.easeOut,132,120,1,true);

    }
```

Comment: change `images_mc.setChildIndex(evt.currentTarget as MovieClip, numChildren-1)` to `images_mc.addChildAt(evt.currentTarget as MovieClip, numChildren-1)`

Comment: when I add that code this message appears "An object cannot be added as a child of itself."

Answer (score 1):

This is a logic problem. You add rolloverF listener to images_mc so images_mc will be the currentTarget. Next you want images_mc to set the index of the currentTarget which is impossible since the currentTarget is images_mc itself. Maybe you mean evt.target?
Also setChildIndex(evt.currentTarget as MovieClip, numChildren-1) or addChildAt(evt.currentTarget as MovieClip, numChildren-1) both translate to a simple addChild().

Comment: Put some code! that should be more simple than these theorical explanations.